# Rails Controller Variables and Complex Relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, relational-database

Let's say we have the following scenario in a Rails application:

`Users` have many `Websites`, and `Websites` have many `Simulations` (likewise, `Websites` belong to `Users`, and `Simulations` belong to `Websites`).

Now the problem is, **how do I display a list of all of a User's Simulations on the User Show page?**

My first gut attempt was to define the following in the `Users Controller`:

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @websites = @user.websites
  @simulations = @user.websites.simulations
end
```

And then use `<%= render @simulations %>` in the `Users Show Page`, but that gives a `NoMethodError`: `undefined method`simulations' for []:Array` when I visit localhost:3000.

So how can I create a variable in my `User Controller` that holds all the `Simulations` that belong to the `Websites` that belong to a particular `User`?

Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is the data in the database?  That error suggests to me that the `@user.websites` method is returning an empty array, so that's why you can't call `#simulations` on it.

Comment: Can you post your models up?And yes that empty array does suggests your table is empty

Comment: I know I have Users and Websites in the database, but I'm not sure that the Simulations has anything in it yet (worst case scenario, the model is defined but there are no instances). But more importantly, do I have the right idea here? I'll try to post up my models.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :websites
  has_many :simulations, :through => :websites
end
```

now you can use `@simulations = @user.simulations` and get all the user's simulations

Comment: Erez, small question: do I have to use `source:` in the line, `has_many :simulations, :through => :websites` ? i don't know what source does, but i noticed that it goes with `:through` in some cases

Comment: You do not have to use the source option as long as your models and has_many associations are made using conventional naming, which is your case. You can look [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_many) for the full documentation of the source option.

Comment: i really like the concept of has_many through, but this didn't work for me because I'm using MongoMapper, which doesn't support a `has_many :through` relationship yet. but thanks anyway! if I were using ActiveRecord, this would have done the trick.

Answer (score 0):

### **Use Erez's answer**

---

You asked for it - I don't know about ruby, but each website in @websites should already contain a field that has a simulation.

This is what you're doing.

1 - You take user, a single object, and get its websites. Cool. User looks something like this (in pseudocode):

```
 Object @user
    {
         Array[] websites = [(Website)site1, (Website)site2];
    }
```

Alright, that's cool. So `user.websites` should return an array of websites.

2 - You try to get the simulations from a website. A website probably looks like this:

```
 Object @website
    {
         Array[] simulations = [(Simulation)sim1, (Simulation)sim2];
    }
```

Hm, why doesn't it work? Well lets break down what you're doing:

```
@user.websites.simulations
```

You're taking `websites`, which is an array, and trying to reference a variable that belongs to a `website` type and not an `array` type.  `@user.websites` is an array object that holds websites, not a website itself.  What you want is to get `@website.simulations`, not `websites.simulations`.

So the first step is getting a website. That's easy - one way would be to try to fetch a website from your website array in the user.

```
@User.websites[0] <-- may not be syntactically correct; I don't know ruby.
```

Now if you want to get all of the websites, iterate through them using a loop and push them to a new array. Again in pseudocode:

```
@all_simulations = new Array();
for(@i=0;@i<count(@user.websites);@i++) //first loop through the websites
{
     for(@q=0;@q<count(@user.websites[@i].simulations);@q++) //then loop through the simulations
     {
           @all_simulations.push(@user.websites[@i].simulations[@q]); //push the simulation into @all_websites
     }
}
```

What we do here is we go into each website in the `user.websites` array and then grab each simulation from that website and throw that into our `@all_simulations` variable.  If you understand the concept, you should be able to convert this logic into valid ruby.

Comment: Remember that all of this is in pseudocode. Don't copy and paste, this is not in valid ruby syntax.

Comment: This is not correct.  `@user.websites` is a method call that produces an array of websites, but that doesn't mean that `@user.websites.simulations` is accessing a property of that array.  `@user.websites.simulations` is also a method call, and the way that the OP wrote it is correct. `@user.websites` won't produce anything because there's no direct linkage between Users and Websites.

Comment: are you serious? I assumed `websites` was an array property of `user`.  Regardless, OP stated that there's a hasMany between User and Websites, and if there's also a hasMany between Websites and Simulations, then iterating through what's returned from the websites() method call should fetch the simulations.

Comment: btw this is spoken from a POV of what I assume from a regular MVC framework - I have no experience w/ RoR

Comment: Sort of.  `websites` is it's own entity with a foreign key pointing to `users`, so `@user.websites` isn't primarily calling to the `users` table, it's calling to the `websites` table for rows with a `user_id` that matches that of `@user`.  It _does_ return an array of `websites`,  but it's not exactly a property of `@user`.  Same with `simulations`, with a foreign key pointing to `websites`.  So you'd need to traverse those relationships to get all of a users simulations. I believe Erez Rabih has the right idea below.

Comment: BTW, above I meant to write "`@user.simulations` won't produce anything because there's no direct linkage between Users and Simulations".  Sorry!

Comment: I don't think I ever said anything about @users.simulations - i just made a separate variable to throw everything into. It looks that the other answers are much more efficient and rails-like. I would avoid using my method.

Answer (score 0):

In your user model add this method. This will produce 2 queries but still better then joining simulations in ruby code.

```
def websites_simulations
  Simulation.where(website_id: website_ids)
end
```